# I am getting blank response from webhook url which I am using for Stripe events

Tags: php, wordpress, stripe-payments

I am getting blank response from the stripe webhook url.

I am using the below code:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
$action = json_decode($json, true);
```

But in ***$json*** array, I am getting blank response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean that the `$action` array is empty. My guess would be - and I've never looked in there - that the body of the request coming from `php://input` isn't JSON.

The code I use is basically the same as the example on Stripe's site and it works just fine for me:

```
    $payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
    $sig_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'];
    $event = null;
    try {
        $event = Webhook::constructEvent(
            $payload,
            $sig_header,
            $this->stripeApiKey
        );
    } catch (\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
        throw new BadRequestHttpException('Unexpected value error');
    } catch (SignatureVerification $e) {
        throw new BadRequestHttpException('Signature verification error');
    }
```

After this point you should have a valid event in `$event` and its core object can be fetched with `$object = $event->data->object`. What type this object will be will depend on what events you are getting webhook calls for. You can get the event type out with `$event->type`.

(Yes, I know using `@` is bad practice,  but I don't really mind failures there as everything is to do with whether `Webhook::constructEvent()` works or not.)